# output of the following is:user client-id=***masked***.host client--id=***masked***.some fix client-num=12564

Tags: java, regex

why host and user strings are printing in the output???

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class String_Match4 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String input = "user client-id=12345.host client-id=745896.some fix client-num=12564";
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(client-id=)(\\d+)");
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(input);
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        System.out.println(result);
        while (m1.find()) {
            m1.appendReplacement(result, m1.group(1) + "***masked***");
        }
        m1.appendTail(result);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you format your code properly with CRTL+K? and add more details to question?

Comment: You really need to add some extra details to this question about what you're trying to do, what you expected to happen, what happened instead, what your question is, etc.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: If no feedback is provided, I think it is reasonable to close the question as unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, YES YOU ARE adding them into the StringBuffer object "result."  That's what Matcher.appendReplacement(sb,replacementString) does.

Comment: i am adding only group(1) but why user and host is printing?? <br>